# H1B Stamping required on new passport?

Tags: visas, usa, passport-renewals

I have H1B stamping on my current passport that is going to expiry in 4 months. I am still at India and first time travel to USA. If I take a new passport,

1) Do I need to go for stamping again?

2) Will they invalidate the valid visas in old passport?

3) Simply, Can I use old passport?

 please suugest!

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to use the old passport. I believe it is possible to use the Visa that the old passport has, but not really use the old passport.

Comment: No, no, and Yes (you can use the visa in the old passport however you need to use it together with a new passport). Voted close question because H1B not covered here

Comment: Please ask at [Expatriates.SE].

Answer (score 3):

1. No, not while the visa remains valid
2. No
3. Yes, together with your new one. You **must** present both at immigration, the old one open at the visa page, and the new one open at the main ID page

Source: [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&SECTION=VI&COUNTRY=us&SUBSECTION=AI&ExpertMode22=&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> A passenger may enter the USA with a valid visa in an
>     expired passport, provided also holding a valid passport of
>     the same nationality